# I want to type "g++" instead of "i686-pc-cygwin-g++" on Cygwin64 Terminal?

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

Everytime I have to compile with Cygwin64 Terminal, I have to write

`$ i686-pc-cygwin-g++ myFile.cpp`

Is there a way I can tell Cygwin that whenever I type `g++` I'm actually referring to `i686-pc-cygwin-g++` since it says `-bash: g++: command not found`
 when I type `g++` .

Comment: Not sure if it works with Cygwin, but you can try typing, at terminal: `alias g++=i686-pc-cygwin-g++`

Comment: Try to edit the .bashrc file. Put an alias in it somewhat like-
alias g++='i686-pc-cygwin-g++'. Then reopen the terminal or source your .bashrc. It can be found in your home directory.

Comment: type "google bash alias" into your web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Amadeus mentioned, it worked :

`$ alias g++=i686-pc-cygwin-g++`

Made me able to type `g++` instead of `i686-pc-cygwin-g++`

Answer (score 1):

If there are no at all link to g++ in one of standard directories, like `/usr/bin/g++`, just create it.
Soft link:

```
ln -s 'path/to/i686-pc-cygwin-g++' '/usr/bin/g++`
```

Or even hard link:

```
ln 'path/to/i686-pc-cygwin-g++' '/usr/bin/g++'
```

Those are base commands, must be available in any bash shell.

The directory `/usr/bin` must be in the standard search path.
If link exists or if you use several compilers and want to switch between them, you can install and use update-alternatives, like

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /path/to/i686-pc-cygwin-g++ 10
```

where 10 is priority.

Switch between them with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

remove all:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
```